# [Tortoise SVN]: The Windows Context Menu Doesn't Show Check-In option

Tags: tortoisesvn, aptana

I installed Tortoise SVN and configured it with Aptana Studio. When I right-click on the folder that I have added into Tortoise repository, it shows the Check-Out option, but not the Check-In option. Why?

Even in Aptana IDE, it is not showing Check-In.

Comment: I didn't know tortoise worked with eclipse editors. It was my understanding you were locked in with either the subclipse or subversive plugins.

Comment: SVN has no such thing as check in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Commit" option should be what you're looking for.

Comment: You've probably not checked out the code from the repository. If you're in a checked-out folder, the context menu should show you a "Commit" option. 

TortoiseSVN has very good [documentation][1], it should help you. 


  [1]: http://tortoisesvn.net/support

Answer (score 1):

In other version control systems, you have to get a local working copy of the repository, which is initially read-only. Then you have to explicitly "check out" a file before you can edit it and then you "check in" once you're done.

In SVN terms, however, "check out" is the operation of creating a local working copy of the repository (or a subtree of it). Once you have the working copy, it is already editable; you don't need to do an explicit action before you can edit the file. SVN will track automatically whether the file was modified locally and once that happens, SVN will offer you "commit" option, which will submit your changes to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Either, as hexium says, you're looking for the wrong thing, or you have it hidden in a submenu. Explore the settings option inside of the SVN submenu, to choose whether commit is displayed on the root context menu or in a submenu.